# PHP MYSQL Select and Insert but not work

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 table: "`customer`" and "`data`".
I want to select from "`customer`" with `mysqli_fetch_array()` and insert some data to "`data`" but I can't insert with this code please help me.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(~0);

    $serverName = "localhost";
    $userName = "root";
    $userPassword = "root";
    $dbName = "mydatabase";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($serverName,$userName,$userPassword,$dbName);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

?>
<table width="600" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th width="91"> <div align="center">URL </div></th>
    <th width="98"> <div align="center">Board </div></th>
    <
  </tr>
<?php
while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><?php echo $result[$objResult["url"];?></div></td>
    <td><?php echo $result["board"];?></td>

  </tr>
<?php

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO data (url,board) VALUES ('".$result["url"]."','".$result["board"]."')";

    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);


}
?>
</table>
<?php
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: what error are getting you ?

Comment: Not error but can't insert to "data" is empty.

Comment: Do fake, hardcoded values into that statement and see if it inserts, like: `"INSERT INTO data (url,board) VALUES ('test','test')";`. If it does, then you know it's what you are inserting that is the problem.

Comment: Also do `print_r($result);` See if it's what you are expecting.

Comment: Last, check the columns in your database, make sure they are spelled correctly, that they can accommodate the amount of characters and that they are the correct type (`varchar` vs `int` for example). There is a lot of troubleshooting you can do.

Comment: @Rasclatt It can insert first time but second time can't insert. So,if table "data" is empty of data,It can insert but if not empty it can't insert

Comment: Have you tried using `mysqli_error($conn);` to see if there is a mysql error?

Comment: mysqli_error($conn); not error. :(

Comment: Have you tried using the multi-query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924127/two-mysqli-queries  I am just guessing, I use PDO so I can't really definitively say.

Comment: @Rasclatt please show code, I am new for PHP

Answer (score 0):

I found 1 syntax error in your code.

You have error here

```
<?php echo $result[$objResult["url"];?>
```

which should be

```
<?php echo $result["url"];?>
```

check my code.

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(~0);

    $serverName = "localhost";
    $userName = "root";
    $userPassword = "";
    $dbName = "mydatabase";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($serverName,$userName,$userPassword,$dbName);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer";

    $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
?>
<table width="600" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th width="91"> <div align="center">URL </div></th>
    <th width="98"> <div align="center">Board </div></th>
      </tr>
<?php
while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div align="center">
        <?php echo $result["url"];?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $result["board"];?></td>

  </tr>
<?php

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO data (url,board) VALUES ('".$result["url"]."','".$result["board"]."')";
$query2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
}
?>
</table>
<?php
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

dont forget to change your connection parameters.

here is the SQL Script :

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer`;
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `board` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

---

-- Records of customer

---

INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES ('1', 'First URL', 'Bord 1');
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES ('2', 'Second URL', 'Board 2');
INSERT INTO `customer` VALUES ('3', null, null);

---

-- Table structure for data

---

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `data`;
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `board` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

---

-- Records of data

---

INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('1', 'First URL', 'Bord 1');
INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('2', 'First URL', 'Bord 1');
INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('3', 'Second URL', 'Board 2');
INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('4', 'First URL', 'Bord 1');
INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('5', 'Second URL', 'Board 2');
INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('6', 'First URL', 'Bord 1');
INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('7', 'Second URL', 'Board 2');
INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('8', 'First URL', 'Bord 1');
INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('9', 'Second URL', 'Board 2');
INSERT INTO `data` VALUES ('10', '', '');

Comment: True, if "data" is empty it can insert but now empty can't insert :)

Comment: it depends of your table design if it allow inserting null value. 
still let me check

Comment: in my case . i have added blank value in customer table ,  and its working .  it allows me to insert blank value in the table "data".

Comment: let me add the SQL script , you will get better idea , i have just edited the answer ,  please check it

Comment: this is data sturcture. CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
  `no` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `board` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `topic` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user`),
  KEY `no` (`no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;

Comment: this is customer structure.CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `no` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `board` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `pr` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `da` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `smf` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;

Comment: actually problem is with your Primary key..  In data table your primary key is user column.  keep id as your primary key, and it should be auto increment, your problem will be resolved for sure.

Comment: I will try and tell result to you soon.

Comment: Finally, I can solve this problem thank you everybody.

Comment: I set same primary key in 2 table :)