# Execute SQL Query with PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am new to using PHP to run SQL commands but what I'm trying to do is truncate specific tables within my database when the script is run. I can do this fine truncating just one table but when I attempt multiple table I run into issues! Code is below, any pointers?! Thanks in advance

```
 <?php
    var_dump($_POST);
    $myServer = $_POST['host'];
    $myUser = $_POST['user'];
    $myPass = $_POST['password'];
    $myDB = $_POST['db'];

    $con = mysqli_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass) or die("Connection 
    Failed");
    mysqli_select_db($con, $myDB)or die("Connection Failed");


    $query = ("
        SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

        TRUNCATE table customers;

        TRUNCATE table customers2;

        SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;


    ");

    if(mysqli_query($con, $query)){
    echo "table empty";}
    else{
     echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));}


    ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two mysqli queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924127/two-mysqli-queries)

Comment: Your query should not have parenthesis surrounding it. You cannot pass multiple statements into a mysqli query. Either do multiple queries or use mysqli_multi_query.

Comment: You said you run into issues. "issues" as? any error messages or something?

Comment: try executing one query per call to mysqli_query(). not 4 at once

Comment: Thank you all, you beautiful people! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

execute one query at a time

```
mysqli_query($con, "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;");
mysqli_query($con, "TRUNCATE table customers;");
mysqli_query($con, "TRUNCATE table customers2;");
mysqli_query($con, "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;");
```

or use `mysqli_multi_query`

```
mysqli_multi_query($con, "
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; 
TRUNCATE table customers;
TRUNCATE table customers2;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
");
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query` only allows one query at a time. If you want to use multiple queries at once, use `mysqli_multi_query`. Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

In your code, you would change

```
mysqli_query($con, $query)
```

to

```
mysqli_multi_query($con, $query)
```