# Why can I not perform SQL injection on this vulnerable script?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, sql-injection

could you please tell me why my SQL-Injection isn't working and how can I fix it. I tried to go after the example from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), but value'); DROP TABLE table;-- or password 1=1 doesn' work. Im sorry to steal your time with these easy things, but I tried it many times and I didn't get it running and the other post didn't help me.

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','' ,'DB') or die(mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($connection ,'DB')or die(mysqli_error());
@$unsafe_variable = $_POST['vorname'];
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `Persons` (`Vorname`) VALUES ('$unsafe_variable')");
```

Comment: Probably due to the same reasons as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924127/two-mysqli-queries

Comment: @danihp now i get a parse error (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')')

Comment: be sure sql injected is right. You must to post something like: `pepe'); DROP TABLE table;--`

Comment: @NigelRen I tried i got no error but the Table is still there.

Comment: @danihp i tried with exactly your command but the table is still there.

Comment: also the 'pepe' value is inserted?

Comment: This doesn't work because `mysqli_query()` will only perform ONE query. If it sees a `;` it will ignore everything after that. To perform TWO queries (`INSERT` and `DROP TABLE`) in one go, use [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query)

Comment: @rickdenhaan, this makes sense. nice.

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO `Persons` (`Vorname`) VALUES ('$unsafe_variable')";
$result = mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query); like this? @rickdenhaan but the command still doesnt get executed.

Comment: Thank you all its Working @rickdenhaan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Making sql injection vulnerable code (for testing purposes):

In order to test SQL Injection with your code we need to make some few changes:

```
<?php

  $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','' ,'DB') or 
                die(mysqli_error($connection));  //1
  mysqli_select_db($connection ,'DB') or die(mysqli_error($connection)); //2
  $unsafe_variable = $_POST['vorname'];
  mysqli_multi_query($connection,    //3
               "INSERT INTO `Persons` (`Vorname`) VALUES ('$unsafe_variable')");

?>
```

- **//1** and **//2**: `mysqli_error` needs $connection parameter.
- **//3**: Only `mysqli_multi_query` is able to execute more than one sentence at a time. For security reasons. `mysqli_query` just executes one to prevent sql injection.

#### Testing:

It's the time to test sql injection. We create a simple table `t` to check if we can drop it through sql injection:

```
create table t ( i int );
```

Time to attack, the killer string to inject sql is:

> **pepe'); DROP TABLE t;--**

[image]

> **SQL with injected code:**
>
> "INSERT INTO Persons (Vorname) VALUES ('**pepe'); DROP TABLE t;--**')"

#### Explained:

- SQL pattern is: `"INSERT INTO Persons (Vorname) VALUES ('$unsafe_variable')"`
- "**pepe');**" replaces `$unsafe_variable`  :  `"INSERT INTO Persons (Vorname) VALUES ('pepe'); DROP TABLE t;--')"`
- Remember **--** means "comments from here", then the last quote and parenthesis is a comment.

After post this value to form:

```
mysql> select * from t;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 's.t' doesn't exist
```

#### How to avoid SQL Injection?

Man, this is Internet, they are a lot of papers about it. Start your searching with Parameterized Queries.