# Combining 2 Queries with OR operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert something to a table and also delete at the same time so my query is like this
`$query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM inventory_item WHERE status = 'Unserviceable' OR DELETE * FROM inventory_item WHERE status = 'Available")
        or die ("Error: Could not fetch rows!");
        $count = 0;`

I wanted to insert datas with Unserviceable status and at the same time delete datas with Available status but its not working.
I'm not really familiar with queries and just starting out.

Comment: There’s no insert statement and why would you want to do them at the same time? They cannot be combined like this. OR is for logical conditions.

Comment: This looks like two separate queries.  The OR is not valid syntax.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen the insert statement is in another page. How do I update the tables and delete something at the same time?

Comment: You don’t. You do them one after another

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid SQL syntax.

If you want to issue two queries, one to INSERT and one to DELETE, then you can send them as two separate calls to `mysqli_query`().  There appears to be an alternate function `mysqli_multi_query()` that allows multiple statements to be included which you can [read about here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924127/two-mysqli-queries).

Finally, if you want the two separate queries to execute as a single unit (that is, if one of them fails then *neither* is executed) then you should research the subject of database transactions, which allow you to execute multiple queries and commit or roll back the entire set of queries as a unit.