# PHP not throwing error for multiple queries

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling, mysqli-multi-query

I have some PHP code to execute multi queries and one of the queries has an error in it. But PHP is not detecting it. Here's the code

```
        $updateCategoriesQ = "DELETE FROM category_products WHERE product = $id; INSERT INTO category_products (category, products) VALUES ";
        foreach ($product['categories'] as $key) {
            $updateCategoriesQ .= "(".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $key)."', $id), "; //error is here in the quote
        }
        $updateCategoriesQ = rtrim($updateCategoriesQ, ', ');
        o($updateCategoriesQ);

        $updateCategories = mysqli_multi_query($connect, $updateCategoriesQ);
        if($updateCategories){
            o('query ok'); //receives this output (wrapper function for echo)
        }
```

The query that forms is

```
DELETE FROM category_products WHERE product = 1; INSERT INTO category_products (category, products) VALUES (1', 1), (2', 1)
```

The second query has an error but PHP says its ok. If I create an error in the first query (delete) then it does throws the error but not if the error is in the second query. Is there a different method of capturing error here?

Comment: do you have error reporting enabled and configured properly? check phpinfo() output to verify your config.

Comment: `mysqli_multi_query()` only returns the success of the first query. To get the results of the second query you have to call `mysqli_next_result()`.

Comment: I recommend against using `mysqli_multi_query()`. There's very little gain and it makes things more complicated.

Comment: Also, you can't use prepared statements with multi-query. This is preferable to using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: @Barmar I hear your recommendations but could you share an example of this? I haven't been able to find it. I see how to use the results of it but not how to check if query was successful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I run two mysqli queries? The second one fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924127/why-cant-i-run-two-mysqli-queries-the-second-one-fails)

Comment: @Dharman I've challenged many commenters like you to SQL inject my code but none have succeeded yet. Thanks for the linked question, I was not able to find it before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `mysqli_multi_query()`! You can only use this query if you have no user input and even then it is really cumbersome and unnecessary.

Instead use prepared statements. This is the recommended and secure way.

```
// Add this before new mysqli() to enable error reporting
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$stmtDel = $connect->prepare('DELETE FROM category_products WHERE product = ?');
$stmtDel->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmtDel->execute();

$stmtInsert = $connect->prepare('INSERT INTO category_products (category, products) VALUES(?, ?)');
$stmtInsert->bind_param('ss', $key, $id);
foreach ($product['categories'] as $key) {
    $stmtInsert->execute();
}
```

As you can see here I have two separate queries and I execute the second one multiple times. This is faster, more secure and it will throw all the errors.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation of `mysqli_multi_query()` says:

> Returns `FALSE` if the first statement failed. To retrieve subsequent errors from other statements you have to call [`mysqli_next_result()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.next-result.php) first.

```
$updateCategories = mysqli_multi_query($connect, $updateCategoriesQ);
if($updateCategories){
    o('delete query ok');

    $insertCategories = mysqli_next_result($connect);
    if ($insertCategories) {
        o('insert query ok');
    } else {
        o('insert query failed: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
    }
} else {
    o('delete query failed: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
}
```

Comment: I don't get any output from this

Answer (score -1):

Okay, with the help of @Barmar and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46149674/4348570) here's a good way to capture errors on subsequent queries.

```
        $updateCategories = mysqli_multi_query($connect, $updateCategoriesQ);
        if($updateCategories){
            do {
                mysqli_next_result($connect);
                $result = mysqli_store_result($connect);
                if (!$result) {
                   o(mysqli_error($connect));
                }
            } while (mysqli_more_results($connect));
        } else {
            o(mysqli_error($connect));
        }
```

Comment: You seem to have missed the better answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58783101/1839439 **You should not execute `mysqli_multi_query()` with variable input!**

Comment: I did not miss it. I understand the drawbacks and pitfalls of multi query and I decided to go with it anyway. Also I wanted a solution for this problem even if I don't use it.