# Trying to update multiple database rows in single query, not working

Tags: php, xml, database, mysqli, sql-update

I have a php script that stores match data (and other data), to a database. I had previously had it running through the xml file with a foreach, and storing/updating each record 1 at a time.

Seeing as there are over 3,000 match records, when updating, it would take over 45 seconds to complete. So I am trying to do it by using one query, rather than thousands of individual queries.

```
$updateQuery = "";
$data = simplexml_load_file('$url');

foreach($data->match as $match) {
    $matchId = intval($match->id);
    $homeTeamName = $match->homeTeamName;
    $homeTeamScore = intval($match->homeTeamScore);
    $awayTeamScore = intval($match->awayTeamScore);
    $awayTeamName = $match->awayTeamName;

    // Check if record exists
    $query = "SELECT `matchId` FROM `matches` WHERE `matchId` = " . $matchId;
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query); 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1 ){
        $updateQuery .= "UPDATE `matches` 
                    SET
                    `homeTeamName`='" . $homeTeamName . "',
                    `homeTeamScore`=" . $homeTeamScore . ",
                    `awayTeamScore`=" . $awayTeamScore . ",
                    `awayTeamName`='" . $awayTeamName . "'
                    WHERE `matchId`=" . $matchId . "; ";
    } else {
        $sql_statement="INSERT INTO `matches` 
                (`matchId`, `homeTeamName`, `homeTeamScore`, `awayTeamScore`, `awayTeamName`) 
                VALUES 
                (" . $matchId . ",
                '" . $homeTeamName . "', 
                " . $homeTeamScore . ", 
                " . $awayTeamScore . ", 
                '" . $awayTeamName . "')";
        mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql_statement);
    }
}
mysqli_query($mysqli,$updateQuery);
```

Please ignore the two types of queries (update/insert), once I get the update working, I will be changing the insert query to work similarly.

What I am finding is that when I view the result of $updateQuery, I can manually select it, place it into the phpmyadmin sql entry, and it works, it updates thge records, so the query being created isn't the issue (snippet below). But when I run the php script, the database doesn't get updated.

**Snippet of the query generated:**
    UPDATE `matches` SET `homeTeamName`='Manchester_United', `homeTeamScore`=2, `awayTeamScore`=1, `awayTeamName`='Leicester_City' WHERE `matchId`=111981; UPDATE `matches` SET `homeTeamName`='AFC_Bournemouth', `homeTeamScore`=2, `awayTeamScore`=0, `awayTeamName`='Cardiff_City' WHERE `matchId`=108933;

What am I missing?

Comment: `mysqli_query` only executes 1 query. You should parameterize your query and just execute it in the loop 1 at a time. Look into `insert into... on duplicate update`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: You cannot submit more than one statement unless you're using mysqli_multi_query.

Comment: You can make matchId a unique field, if it isn't already, then use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, then you can build all of the rows into one query.

Comment: Thanks guys, changed it to 'mysqli_multi_query', and now it works fine :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php/mysql with multiple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610675/php-mysql-with-multiple-queries)

Comment: Well that fixed one problem, and gave me another :p I have multiple xml files being read. Now when it moves onto the next select query (checking for record), I get the 'mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given'. Works fine for the first check, but not the ones after it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `$updateQuery .=` in this code **.=** don't use `.` if you not already have same var.

Comment: There are some security implications to using `mysqli_multi_query` and you are injecting values into this query, `'" . $awayTeamName  . "')`. Multi queries allow a attacker to do things like this `$awayTeamName  =  "'); CREATE USER 'haxor'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; --";`  Where they can hi-jack your query and run a completely different one.  Even if this comes from an XML file are you willing to take that risk?

Comment: @Deepak, I am fairly noob at PHP and I used `.=` as it runs through a foreach loop, and runs the query at the end, so thought that was the only way to add on to the end of that variable rather than overwrite it which `=` does. Is there a better way?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - Its on a localhost, so not that worried about it. In the end I went with just truncating the table each time, and doing away with the update query. 

I found just inserting each time took a few seconds to run, where as individually updating was taking minutes. 

The data does come from an XML file. Just for future reference what way would you have done it? I am still learning, and any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: @Dean84 Use can use array for taking value.